# Space characters inside Oracle's Contains() function

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I needed to use Oracle 11g's Contains() function to search some exact text contained in some field typed by the user. I was asked not to use the 'like' operator.

According to the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqspcl.htm), for everything to work you need to:

- Double `}` characters
- Put the whole input between `{}`

This works in most cases except for a few ones. Below it a test case:

```
create table theme
  (name varchar2(300 char) not null);

insert into theme (name)
values ('a');

insert into theme (name)
values ('b');

insert into theme (name)
values ('a or b');

insert into theme (name)
values ('Pdz344_1_b');

create index name_index on theme(name) indextype is ctxsys.context;
```

If the `'or'` operator was interpreted, I would get all four results, which is hopefully not the case.  Now if I run the following, I would expect is to only find `'a or b'`.

```
select * from theme
where contains(name, '{a or b}')>0;
```

However I also get `'Pdz344_1_b'`. But there's no `'a'`, `'o'` not `'r'` and I find it very surprising that this text is matched. Is there something I don't get about contains()'s syntax?

Comment: What `SCORE` do you get for the different rows?

Comment: 'a or b' -> 3; 'Pdz344_1_b' -> 3; all others 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CONTAINS` is not like `LIKE` operator at all. Since it using `ORACLE TEXT` search engine (something like google search), not just string matching.

`{}` - is an escape marker. Means everything you put inside should be treated as text to escape.

Therefore you issue query to find text that looks like `a or b` not like `a` or `b`.
So your query get matched against `Pdz344_1_b` because it has `b` char in it.

Row with only `a` character ain't matched because `a` character exists in the [default stop list](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/astopsup.htm#i634475).

Why just `b` ain't matched? Because your match sequence actually looks like `a\ or\ b`.
So we have 3 tokens `a` `_or` `_b` (underscores represents spaces). `a` in stop list, and we have no string `_b` in the `b` row, because there only single character. But we do have this combination in the `Pdz344_1_b` row, because non-alphabetic characters are treated as whitespace. If you remove `{}` or query for  `{b or a}` then you'll get matches against `b` as well.

Comment: If it returned `Pdz344_1_b` because it contains `b`, then all other three results should have been returned, too, which is not the case.

Comment: And it was a typo, I'm actually using varchar2

Comment: Mmm, so did I misunderstood your question and you want to know why "a" and "b" rows ain't matched, rather then why "Pdz344_1_b" was matched? Lemme check the docs, but if I remember it right, there are some filtering to avoid indexing single letters and so on.

Comment: jfyi, you can check generated tokens. There is a tables after oracle text index creation that starts with DR$ prefix, in your case `DR$NAME_INDEX$I` will contain tokens for oracle text. 'a' shouldn't be matched, because this letter exist in default stop list check this link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/astopsup.htm#i634475 . 'b' ain't matched for some other reason, but thats cause of your query, since it's token are exist.

Comment: For the purpose of my application where I need to search for potentially common english words, I've empties the default stop-list and everything is fine now